# PHP string to numeric conversion with decimal places

Tags: php

I have a string (`$maxDeposit`) which is a numeric monetary value. So, for example:

> 123.00

This string is being passed in to jQuery, it needs to be passed in as a numeric data type. I'm achieving this using the following:

```
$maxDeposit = floatval($maxDeposit);
```

This loses the last last decimal place however, so my number looks like:

> 123.0

I have this method of converting the number to two decimal places:

```
$maxDeposit =  sprintf('%0.2f', round($maxDeposit, 2));
```

However this also converts the number back to a string. Is there a way I can convert the string to a float but keep the last decimal place? Thanks

Comment: Do that in javascript `parseFloat()` If you are sending data to javascript as JSON its going to be converted to a string anyway

Answer (score 2):

No, `float` is a numeric value, and `123.00` is its representation with 2 decimal places. It is responsibility of view layer to format numbers. In your case it is jQuery, e.g. `console.log(maxDeposit.toFixed(2))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, You can use floatval/float and number_format.

```
$maxDeposit = number_format(floatval($maxDeposit), 2);
```

or

```
number_format((float)$maxDeposit, 2, '.', '');
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php